# Movie about a man and a worm inside his head

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this late 1980's(?) movie in the mid/late 1990s when I was only young, so sorry for the lack of details.

I remember there was a main character - man, some sort of a junkie. 
There was also a worm. Maggot. He would get inside man's head, make him hallucinate and, I think, do some terrible stuff. The guy had the addiction from the worm but also tried to fight him somehow.

Movie had this dark, gloomy, terminator-ish atmosphere.

Comment: When were you 6 or 7?

Comment: 1996-1997. I'd say movie itself was somewhere from the late 80s.

Comment: Heh, after adding '80s' to the google query, I've found it quite easy by myself. 

It's "Brain Damage" (1988).

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094793/

Don't know whether I should delete this question since I've found answer by myself so I'll just leave it for mods.

Comment: Just add the result of your search as an answer. Then it's visible for other people having the same question as well.

Comment: Alright, I'll just have to wait for 8 hours since I have no reputation.

Comment: I have been wondering what this particular movie was for about twenty years. Good work finding it.

Comment: I'm not sure "Brain Damage" fits your description.  The worm in "Brain Damage" went my the name Elmer, and I remember the movie's atmosphere being colorful and '80s-ish.

Comment: Well, it was a long time ago so my memories could be cloudy. But the moment I saw the trailer, I knew that was it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "[Brain Damage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094793/)" (1988).

> Brian begins an unwilling symbiotic relationship with a malevolent leech-like brain-eating parasite called "Aylmer". Aylmer secretes a highly addictive, hallucinogenic blue fluid into Brian's brain. In return for a steady supply of the fluid, Brian must seek out human victims for Aylmer, so that he can devour their brains. All the while, though, as Brian adopts a heavily secluded life in his indulgence of Aylmer's fluids, it begins to draw a rift in his relationship with his girlfriend Barbara and his brother.

Apparently not as dark and gloomy as I remember it but still pretty creepy.

Comment: It sounds like it’s based on ["Enoch"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/a-short-story-about-a-man-enslaved-by-a-tiny-demon-who-forces-him-to-commit-mur/138677#138677)