# Imaginary friend tries to kill a boy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I am looking for a short story from around the 1970s. It was a horror story about a boy who lived near a lake. He had an imaginary friend that ended up trying to kill him.

Comment: Long shot, but possibly Robert Bloch's "Enoch"? See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/a-short-story-about-a-man-enslaved-by-a-tiny-demon-who-forces-him-to-commit-mur for details on that story.